# K-50 controls keep freezing up

Tags: troubleshooting, pentax

I have a Pentax K-50 that seems to be exhibiting a problem, but I'm not sure if it's just something I'm doing wrong.

While using the camera, I sometimes find that it won't let me change the aperture or shutter time. When I move the front and back "e-dials" the numbers on the screen just don't change, as if I wasn't moving the dial. This seems to happen more or less at random. If I switch to a different mode and then back again this seems to fix it, until the next time it happens.

In addition, sometimes when using exposure bracketing it only takes the first two shots, even though I continue to hold down the button. Usually if I try again it takes all three.

Are these issues likely to indicate a problem that will need repair, or is it possible that I'm just doing something incorrect that causes this to happen?

Both problems seem to happen with more than one lens, though I did just buy the two lenses I'm using second hand. So I guess the problem is with the body rather than the lenses, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does it happen frequently or occasionally? What mode is typically used? Very occasionally, my K50 will wind up between modes or in another mode when I take it out of the bag [occurrence/shutterRelease ~0.03%]. I don't take particular care when putting it in or out of my bag. I haven't had an issue with exposure bracketing, but I have very rarely used it...I prefer chimpping.

Comment: It happens fairly often, more than once per day. I don't think it's between modes, partly because this starts happening during use, i.e. it's working fine and then at some point it stops working and I have to change modes to get it to start again. But I will make sure to check that next time I use it.

Comment: Sounds more like broken to me. Though when I use mine in the rain, I will have to turn it off and on from time to time to reset the internal state. So rain is another possible factor. Does turning it off and on fix the dial issue?

Comment: Yes, either turning it off and on or just switching to another mode and back will fix it temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured this out. My camera is not broken, and it was indeed something I was doing wrong. I'll describe it here in case it helps others in the future.

I use exposure bracketing a lot, and I had "one-push bracketing" turned off in the settings. I *thought* that what this meant was that if I pressed the shutter release it would take a single exposure, whereas if I held it down it would take three, so that I wouldn't have to worry about turning bracketing off and on again all the time. However, that's not quite the full story. As the manual says,

> When you take your finger off the shutter release button during Exposure Bracketing, the exposure setting will remain effective for twice the amount of the meter operating time (p.97) (default setting is about 20 seconds) and you can take a picture at the next compensation value. After about twice the amount of the meter operating time elapses, the camera returns to settings for taking the first image.

What this means is that pressing the shutter release once *doesn't* just take a single shot, it takes the first of three bracketed exposures. It won't let you change the exposure settings before taking the other two shots. This explains both the "controls locking up" problem and the "only takes two bracketed exposures" problem (since the camera thinks those are the last two out of three). It also explains why I thought the metering on this camera was so horribly inconsistent, which I hadn't realised was part of the same issue.

To resolve it, I guess I have no choice but to fiddle around in the menus turning bracketing on and off again all the time after all, which is a bit sad. I could change the "meter operating time", but this can't be set lower than 3 seconds, so I'd still have to wait six seconds in between shots if I don't want this to happen. You can set the Raw/FX button to exposure bracketing, but that just takes you into the menu, so you still have to fiddle around a bit to turn it off. I'm not sure why the camera doesn't offer the behaviour I originally thought it had.

Comment: Exposure bracketing can be turned on and off from the menu accessed by the right button of the four way controller. The exposure range can be set there as well. The right button of the four way controller accesses [all or most] shutter trigger modes. Personally, I prefer chimping. Glad ain't broken.

Comment: Sure, but since I'm usually using the four way controller to set the focus point it's still a bit of a fiddle - I have to long-press the centre button to exit the focus point mode, then press right, then select the exposure mode I want from the menu, which is quite a lot of actions for something I do in between almost every shot. What is "chimping"?

Comment: 'Chimping' is looking at the recently taken image to adjust settings [I recently switched to four channel histogram mode from one channel based on something I read here]. I agree that it's more fiddly when in focus point selection mode, then again, focus point selection mode is inherently a layer of fiddlyness.